# How to write script in python to reboot android tablet multiple times

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, android-testing

How can I write script in python to reboot android tablet and launch any app multiple times. Is there any better way to automate this test.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I was trying using monkey, monkeyrunner. I was trying to find some examples to kick start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the command `adb reboot` to reboot a device.

There are likely a plethora of ways you could use python to make this adb command. The simplest of which that I can think of is:

```
import os
os.system("adb reboot")
```

you'll have to either put a path infront of adb, run this from the folder that adb is in, or add the folder that adb is in to your system path variable.

If you don't want to go that route (or if you want to do some other more ineteresting things with adb) there exists a [python wrapper around the adb tool](https://github.com/sch3m4/pyadb) that will let you interact with it in a more "pythonic" way than simply running system cmds.

Comment: so I want to reboot machine 100 times and run any app to see it works properly.

Comment: so write a for loop that sends the reboot command and then sleeps for several seconds while the device comes back up. What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, time

for iter in xrange(5):

    adb_reboot = os.popen("sudo adb reboot")
    print(adb_reboot)
    print('Phone is rebooting...')
    time.sleep(15)

    adb_wait = os.popen("sudo adb wait-for-device")
    print(adb_wait)
    time.sleep(15)
    print('Phone rebooted successfully')

    adb_device = os.popen("sudo adb devices -l")
    print(adb_device)
```